# extracting 3x3 matrix of a .xyz file with datatype float64 or merging three 1x3 matrices to one 3x3 matrix

Tags: python-2.7, matrix, 3d, coordinate-transformation

I've come over this issue and after many hours of trying, I'd like to ask someone with more experience in python than me (which should be no problem because I am a python beginner).

There is my input.xyz file with eight points, which looks something like this:

```
15.486586, 46.798954, -6.232800, 15.445764, 46.807576, -6.249205, -0.040822,0.008622, -0.016405, 0.044832;
6.233575, 48.083754, -4.223557, 6.187027, 48.090785, -4.243389, -0.046548, 0.007031, -0.019832, 0.051083;
-2.159452, 40.818712, -3.104244, -2.200572, 40.818489, -3.120266, -0.041120,-0.000223, -0.016022, 0.044132;
45.554111, 131.689322, 1.525740, 45.452954, 131.721406, 1.483290, -0.101157,0.032084, -0.042450, 0.114298;
28.315109, 146.107918, 2.897549, 28.235633, 146.131800, 2.864060, -0.079476,   0.023882, -0.033489, 0.089489;
7.303209, 138.223347, 4.702106, 7.250850, 138.242379, 4.679564, -0.052359, 0.019032, -0.022542, 0.060098;
-32.211983, 148.909744, 12.919538, -32.279077, 148.907541, 12.876267,-0.067095, -0.002203, -0.043271, 0.079868;
-48.926024, 180.295215, 20.142896, -49.008547, 180.275117, 20.127614,-0.082523, -0.020098, -0.015282, 0.086299;
```

The ";" seperates every point and the first three values of one point are the x,y and z values. So I want to take three points with their xyz values und write them in a matrix with python. 
This is what I got so far:

```
# creating empty list for append
xyz_matrx = []


counter = 0
for line in xyz:
    counter += 1
# counter to get only first three columns
    if counter%4 == 0:
        break

    # deleting whitespaces and selecting wanted data
    linevalues = line.strip().split(",")
    x = (linevalues[0:1])
    y = (linevalues[1:2])
    z = (linevalues[2:3])
    xyz_matrx.append(x)

#flatten because xyz_matrix is a list within list
# values converting into float64, because string won't work for following    
#work
flattenedx = [val for sublist in xyz_matrx for val in sublist]
matr_flatx = [float(i) for i in flattenedx]
A_matrx = mat(matr_flatx)
```

with this, I get a 1x3 matrix with the xyz points which are horizontal in the matrix, but I want three columns within the matrix, which stand for each point and rows which stand for xyz values, a 3x3 matrix in datatype float64.
If I change something with the indices, I only get string88 matrices. 
I can create two more lists for the two other points, then I have three 1x3 matrices but ".append" won't work because I don't have a twodimensional matrix?

I know my code isn't very efficient but I hope somebody understood my problem and can help me.

Short: I've got an input .xyz file, only the first three values (x,y,z coordinates) of every point are relevant, I want three points of the xyz with each of their three coordinates in a 3x3 matrix (first column vertical: first point, xyz, second column vertical: second point with xyz and third column third point with xyz vertical down), the datatype has to be float64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it

```
# creating empty list for append
xyz_matrix = []
counter = 0

with open('input.xyz', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        # Add the first three values to the matrix
        xyz_matrix.append(map(float, line.strip().split(",")[0:3]))
        counter += 1
        if counter == 3:
            break

# Transpose
xyz_matrix = zip(*xyz_matrix)

print xyz_matrix
```

You end up with a list of tuples, but that should be OK.

This is more direct, but less general

```
# Creating an empty 2D list
xyz_matrix = [[], [], []]
counter = 0

with open('input.xyz', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        # Add the first three values to the matrix
        values = map(float, line.strip().split(",")[0:3])

        # Append x, y, z to each rows 0, 1, 2 respectively
        for i in range(3):
            xyz_matrix[i].append(values[i])

        counter += 1
        if counter == 3:
            break

print xyz_matrix
```

Comment: thank you very much Peter, the first one already did it for me, I just had to add "matrix_fin = mat(xyz_matrix)" and my matrix was as I wished.